# free() em pilha dinâmica de char não funciona - C

Tags: c, struct, stack

Olá,

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar liberar memória alocada dinamicamente. Para string pequena tem hora que funciona, mas pra string grande o programa capota. Tem hora que string de 3 caracteres ou 4 funciona, tem hora que não.

```
int main()
{
    TPilha* p;
    char str[10];

    scanf("%s",&str);

    p = cria_pilha(10);

    empilha(p,str);
    printf("\n\n");
    desempilha(p);

    libera_pilha(p,0);
    libera_pilha(p,1);
    libera_pilha(p,2);
    libera_pilha(p,3);
    libera_pilha(p,4);
    libera_pilha(p,5);
    libera_pilha(p,6);
    libera_pilha(p,7);
    libera_pilha(p,8);
    libera_pilha(p,9);
    libera_pilha(p,10);

    return 0;
}
```

Na hora de liberar a memória eu fui posição por posição do vetor e fui dando `free()`. Fiz isso pra tentar entender o erro.

O problema começa quando tento digitar algo como `filipi`, e as vezes até algo com três caracteres, como `fhg`, mas estranhamente ele funciona com `fil` ou `fili`.

Minha estrutura é essa:

```
typedef struct pilha TPilha;
struct pilha{
    int topo;
    int prox;
    int tamanho;
    char** PILHA;
};
```

Eu inicializo ela assim:

```
TPilha*cria_pilha(int tam){

    TPilha* aux = (TPilha*)malloc(sizeof(TPilha));
    aux->PILHA = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * tam);
    aux->topo = NULL;
    aux->prox = 0;
    aux->tamanho = tam;

    return aux;
}
```

Pra empilhar eu faço assim:

```
void empilha(TPilha* aux,char* num){

    if(pilha_vazia(aux)!=2){// Só posso empilhar se não for 2, 2 = pilha cheia

        for (int i=0; i<strlen(num); i++){
            aux->PILHA[aux->prox] = num[i];
            aux->topo = aux->prox;
            aux->prox++;
            printf("PILHA[%d] = %c EMPILHADO\n",aux->prox-1,aux->PILHA[aux->topo]);
        }
    }
}
```

Pra desempilhar eu faço:

```
int desempilha(TPilha* aux){
    for (int i=aux->prox; i!=0; i++){
        if(pilha_vazia(aux)==1){
            printf("Pilha vazia\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("PILHA[%d] = %c REMOVIDO\n",aux->topo,aux->PILHA[aux->topo]);
        aux->prox = aux->topo;
        aux->topo--;
    }
}
```

Pra verificar se pilha ta vazia:

```
int pilha_vazia(TPilha* aux){
    if(aux->prox == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(aux->prox == aux->tamanho){
        printf("Pilha cheia\n");
        return 2; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

E para liberar eu faço:

```
void libera_pilha(TPilha* aux,int i){
   //for (int i=0; i<aux->tamanho; i++){
        //free(aux->PILHA[i]);
        printf("liberado - %d\n",aux->PILHA[i]);
        free(aux->PILHA[i]);
    //}
    //free(aux->PILHA);
    //free(aux);
}
```

A ideia é fazer o `free()` com o loop, mas removi ele para fazer um por um e entender onde que ta acontecendo o erro, mas não existe um padrão no erro, tem hora que funciona e tem hora que não. O que está acontecendo?

Quem se interessar eu deixei o código num .rar [aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S7Bms2p_J3nPJeIoVDl68Nm8EdHtSNI8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: não coloque imagens nas perguntas, coloque sempre só texto...é possível que sua pergunta seja fechada por causa disso

Comment: Entendi, vou mudar isso. Obrigado!

Comment: coloque também o código das funções "empilha" e "desempilha"

Comment: Ok, vou colocar. Não tinha colocado pq achei que ia ficar coisa demais.

Comment: Liga os *warnings* do teu compilador (`gcc ... -Wall -Wextra ...`) e toma atenção a eles.

Comment: @pmg farei isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da informação que está na pergunta é possível ver que tem (pelo menos) uma coisa errada: na criação do vetor de ponteiros é necessário inicializar os ponteiros, o que não está sendo feito:

```
TPilha* cria_pilha(int tam) {
    TPilha* aux = (TPilha*)malloc(sizeof(TPilha));
    aux->PILHA = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * tam);
    memset(aux->PILHA, 0, sizeof(char*) * tam);        // faltando
    aux->topo = NULL;
    aux->prox = 0;
    aux->tamanho = tam;
    return aux;
}
```

Atenção: não é praxe usar nomes em maiúsculas para nomes de variáveis ou tipos, apenas para nomes definidos por **#define**.

UPDATE

Na funçao empilha também há um erro

```
void empilha(TPilha* aux, char* num ) {
  if (pilha_vazia(aux) !=2 ) { // Só posso empilhar se não for 2, 2 = pilha cheia
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(num); i++) {
      aux->PILHA[aux->prox] = num[i]; // <------- ERRO
      aux->topo = aux->prox;
      aux->prox++;
      printf("PILHA[%d] = %c EMPILHADO\n",aux->prox-1,aux->PILHA[aux->topo]);
    }
  }
}
```

Na linha destacada está havendo atribuição de um caracter para um ponteiro:

```
aux->PILHA[aux->prox] = num[i]; // <------- ERRO
```

Não analisei a lógica desse comando, mas muito provavelmente tem alguma coisa errada aí.

Comment: Interessante, adicionei essa linha faltando mas ainda assim persiste o erro. Esse código antes era para um vetor de inteiros, e mesmo sem essa inicialização ele funcionava normalmente. Ai eu adaptei ele pra receber caracteres e começou dar erro. Obrigado por mencionar isso, vou estudar essa função memset() que eu não conhecia até então. Sobre o uso de maiúsculas, de fato, realmente não é algo utilizado, vou corrigir esse hábito meu. Obrigado!

Comment: Entendi, vou verificar essa atribuição e volto com um uptade.

Comment: UPDATE: Esse código estava com vários erros, um deles foi mencionado pelo @zentrunix, e a partir do erro mencionado eu fui percebendo outros, por isso vou declarar a resposta dele como solução. O erro principal do código é que eu estava criando um vetor de ponteiros do tipo "ponteiro char", depois eu estava atribuindo um char para um ponteiro, e depois estava tentando liberar memória de uns espaços que não existiam, e tava uma confusão danada. O correto era fazer uma alocação dinâmica de um vetor tipo char, e inserir um caractere por vez, e depois dar free() em PILHA, só isso.